# React Canvas converted to Blob and appended to Formdata initially gives and error and then starts working

Tags: reactjs, canvas, blob, form-data

My react app is for ticket sale that takes an existing image and stamps the guest name on it (using canvas). I have this form that sends a formData to the server

```
 <Formik
                validationSchema={schema}
                onSubmit={async (values) => {
                  try {
                    // Create a canvas element, add the image and text, covert to blob
                    //for 1500 x 485 images
                    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    var layout = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    let ticket = new Image();
                    ticket.src = target.ticket_img;
                    //image
                    canvas.width = ticket.naturalWidth;
                    canvas.height = ticket.naturalHeight;
                    layout.drawImage(
                      ticket,
                      0,
                      0,
                      ticket.naturalWidth,
                      ticket.naturalHeight
                    );
                    // text
                    let textName = values.name;
                    layout.rotate(4.71);
                    layout.font = "52px Archive";
                    layout.fillStyle = "#faf9f6";
                    layout.textAlign = "center";
                    layout.strokeText(textName, -255, 1170);
                    layout.fillText(textName, -255, 1170);

                    layout.font = "52px Archive";
                    layout.fillStyle = "#faf9f6";
                    let textSurname = values.surname;
                    layout.textAlign = "center";
                    layout.strokeText(textSurname, -255, 1230);
                    layout.fillText(textSurname, -255, 1230);
                    // blob
                    const dataBlob = await new Promise((resolve) =>
                      canvas.toBlob((blob) => resolve(blob), "image/webp")
                    );
                    // formData
                    const formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append(
                      "image",
                      dataBlob,
                      target.title +
                      "_" +
                      values.name +
                      values.surname +
                      "_GUEST"
                    );
                    // some more code that is not causing any errors
                  } catch (err) { 
                    console.log(err)
                   }
```

the problem is that when I first submit, I get the following error that comes from the catch block with console.log

TypeError: Failed to execute 'append' on 'FormData': parameter 2 is not of type 'Blob'.
at onSubmit (NonMemberPurchase.jsx:135:1)

and on the second submit (pressing the button once again), the form is submitted without problems and without errors. I suspect that I am scheduling the events poorly but I do not know how to fix it. I also do not want to change the canvas to blob converting functionality as this once works and the others do not output the ticket canvas properly. I am currently using the code as it is but people have started noticing the bug and start complaining that they need to press twice for the form to be submitted. I would appreciate some suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after some sessions I was finally able to figure it out! I shifted my convert canvas to Blob function out of the scope

```
export const createCustomerTicket = async (ticketImage, name, surname) => {
    // Create a canvas element, add the image and text, covert to blob
    //for 1500 x 485 images
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var layout = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let ticket = new Image();
    ticket.src = ticketImage;

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ticket.onload = resolve;
      ticket.onerror = reject;
    });

    //image
    canvas.width = ticket.naturalWidth;
    canvas.height = ticket.naturalHeight;
    layout.drawImage(
      ticket,
      0,
      0,
      ticket.naturalWidth,
      ticket.naturalHeight
    );
    // text
    layout.rotate(4.71);
    layout.font = "52px Archive";
    layout.fillStyle = "#faf9f6";
    layout.textAlign = "center";
    layout.strokeText(name, -255, 1170);
    layout.fillText(name, -255, 1170);

    layout.font = "52px Archive";
    layout.fillStyle = "#faf9f6";
    layout.textAlign = "center";
    layout.strokeText(surname, -255, 1230);
    layout.fillText(surname, -255, 1230);
    
    // blob
    const dataBlob = await new Promise((resolve) =>
      canvas.toBlob((blob) => resolve(blob), "image/webp")
    );

    return dataBlob
  }
```

Then I just call it async in the submit handler

```
 <Formik
                  validationSchema={schema}
                  onSubmit={async (values) => {
                    try {
                      const ticket = await createCustomerTicket(target.ticket_img, values.name, values.surname);
                      // formData
                      const formData = new FormData();
                      formData.append(
                        "image",
                        ticket,
                        target.title +
                        "_" +
                        values.name +
                        values.surname +
                        "_GUEST"
                      );
//other code
```

It works like a charm and I do not get it as a null value anymore!